# Is it possible to choose video quality in TED online player?

Tags: video-streaming, ted

Is there a way to choose a high quality video to watch online on [TED](https://www.ted.com/)?

I can't find such option, and the quality won't change if I'll let it buffer a bit.

When I download the video, it's in better quality, and I can actually watch it. On the website it's pretty pixelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably there's no way to do that.

Here's what they say on [their site](https://support.ted.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2631594-troubleshooting-the-video-player):

> TED uses an HLS-based player (as opposed to Flash) that’s built in-house.
>
> The video player is designed to automatically adjust video quality based on your internet bandwidth. If you find that the video quality is poor or that the video pauses too often, try downloading the talk to watch offline.

Comment: Too bad.. I will probably keep searching each video in YouTube to get it in good quality . Thanks! תודה :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, way to go... תודה לך...

Comment: Now I'm thinking. Why not pressing the Share (to get to the Download link) and instead of left-clicking the Download button right click on it and open the link in a different tab. At least on PC it should play you the higher quality video like you would've downloaded it.

Comment: It just less comfortable, and doesn't have the subtitles option - better on youtube

Comment: I agree that YouTube can be better, but it does have subtitles if you choose subtitles in the download options before opening the link